# ObjectAnimator only effect one time

Tags: android

I add some buttons dynamically and I want when one button click, these button change text and change position on screen.

This is code I used on OnClick method:

```
               for (Button button : mNumberButtons) {
                    button.setText(""+new Random().nextInt(10));
                    ObjectAnimator translateTo50 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                            button, "TranslationY", 50);
                    translateTo50.start();
                }
```

When I click a button on first time, all button change text and also change position as I expect. 
But when I click a button second time, all buttons change text but not change position. So I think the reason is ObjectAnimator.

Can anybody tell me what is the root cause for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

`50` is a static value so first time when you click button it will go to position x = 50, but on next click it is already at x = `50` so it won't translate. You might want to set target x value relative to current position of `Button`, something like -

```
for (Button button : mNumberButtons) {
                    button.setText(""+new Random().nextInt(10));
                    ObjectAnimator translateTo50 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                            button, "TranslationY", button.getX() + 50);
                    translateTo50.start();
                }
```

And of course you will have to check boundary values of screen so that it won't go outside the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the button can change position for second click but now I can not control the position after change. It is not 50 for each change position

Comment: i did not understand the requirement. How much it should translate on second click?